# can't install postgres (because of readline)

Tags: postgresql, homebrew, readline

Trying to install postgresql on my mac via homebrew: `brew install postgresql`

getting this error:

```
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/readline-6.3.5.tar.gz
==> Downloading https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jacknagel/8df5735ae9273bf5ebb

curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404
Error: Failed to download resource "readline--patch"
Download failed: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jacknagel/8df5735ae9273bf5ebb2/raw/827805aa2927211e7c3d9bb871e75843da686671/readline.diff
```

Anybody know of any workarounds to get postgres installed? Or what's going on with the download source?

Comment: If you don't have to install it from homebrew, you can use other source to install postgresql on mac, I installed postgresql on my mac using package by [edb](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload)

Comment: that worked to get postgres installed, but now I can't install the pg gem. getting this error: Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header

Comment: the solution to fix that is by installing postgres via homebrew... back to my original problem

Answer (score 1):

I was running an old version of homebrew. `brew update` fixed that